# Short title in TOC using custom titletoc/titlesec

Tags: table-of-contents, amsbook

I am having trouble with my custom made titletoc/titlesec. I read in the documentation (missed it?), googled and searched this forum but could not find what I needed.

First what I want:

I have a long chapter title and I want a short version of it in the TOC. I found so far to use:

```
\usepackage[toctitles]{titlesec}
\chapter[short for TOC]{long for chapter heading}
```

As I redefined my own TOC this does not work. I guess I would have to enter this in my redefined TOC, but I don’t know how and where. Here what I did in a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,reqno]{amsbook} 

%linksbuendige chapter, section, subsection
\usepackage{titlesec}
\newcommand*{\justifyheading}{\raggedright}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\scshape\justifyheading}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}
 {14pt}{\Large\scshape}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\justifyheading}{\thesection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\justifyheading}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\justifyheading}{\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\itshape\justifyheading}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}


%Inhaltsverzeichnis formatieren
\usepackage{titletoc}
\newcommand\frontmatterchaptoc{%
\titlecontents{chapter}
  [1.4em]{\addvspace{3pt}}
  {\contentslabel{-0.25em}\hspace{2em}}
  {\hspace*{-1.3em}\bfseries}% \MakeUppercase removed
  {\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
} 
\titlecontents{section}[3.7em]{}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsection}[5.9em]{}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}{\hspace*{-2.3em}}
{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[8.9em]{}{\contentslabel{3em}}{\hspace*{-3.3em}}
{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}
\titlecontents{paragraph}[12.6em]{}{\contentslabel{3.7em}}{\hspace*{-3.7em}}
{\titlerule*[0.3pc]{.}\contentspage}


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents

\chapter[Title I want to see in TOC - short]{Title I am seeing in TOC - long}
This is chapter 1

\end{document}
```

It does not matter if I enter

```
\usepackage[toctitles]{titlesec}
```

or just

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

I hope someone knows how to integrate this into what I have so far!

Cheers

Summer

Comment: `\documentclass{amsbook} 
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter[Capybara]{Wombat}
\end{document}
` What i want to say: This is one of the documented features of `amsbook`.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. Do you mean it is not possible with amsbook, or that it should be possible? In the second case, why is it not working (see my minimal example)?

Comment: ams classes do not use the short versioni for the table of contents. Of course, you can redefine stuff and soon a ams person will come along and provide a solution.